# Center element and then place others left and right without changing original center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have three elements.

I would like to center the middle element on the page and then:

- place the right element on the right side of the middle element
- place the left element on the left side of the middle element

**This must all be done without moving the original center, no matter how wide the L/R elements are!**

I already have CSS (`text-align:center` / `margin: 0 auto`) that centers the whole lot of three, but it depends on the width of the L/R elements. I want the widths to not matter.

```
<nav>
  <span class="left">left</span>
  <span class="middle">middle</span>
  <span class="right">right is a longer width perhaps</span>
</nav>

nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

### *CORRECT*

[image: Correct]

---

### *INCORRECT*

[image: Incorrect]

Comment: Can you show some code for the html grouping and css regarding that grouping?

Comment: Ahh, okay the middle is a known or unknown width?

Comment: Everything is unknown (but can be assumed to be reasonable, i.e. not 1000 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/xenuyo

[image]

**HTML**

```
   <ul class="center-me">
      <li><span>80863 Photosdfdfd</span></li>
      <li><span>Someone verylongname</span></li>
      <li><span>Some other Category</span></li>
    </ul>
  

   <ul class="center-me">
      <li><span>80863 Photosdfdfd</span></li>
      <li><span>Verylongname Unbreakingsurname</span></li>
      <li><span>Some other CategoryCould beverylongtooSome other CategoryCould beverylongtoo</span></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-me {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width:550px) { 
    .center-me {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    .center-me li:not(:first-child) {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .center-me li:nth-child(even) {
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 16%;
    }
    .center-me li:first-child {
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .center-me li:last-child {
        padding-left: 16%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .center-me li span {
        padding: 10px 0;
        position: relative; 
        display:block;
    }
    .center-me li:nth-child(even) span:before,
    .center-me li:last-child span:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        top: 0;
        bottom:0;
    }
    .center-me li:nth-child(even) span:before {
        right: -10px;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
    .center-me li:last-child span:before {
        border-left: 1px solid red;
        left: -10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've achieved what you're trying to do, please check:

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
span.right {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
span.middle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
span.left {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<nav>
  <span class="left">left</span>
  <span class="middle">middle</span>
  <span class="right">right is a longer width perhaps</span>
</nav>
```

The `middle` always stays centered regardless of how much content you add inside the left or the right `span` tag. The heading above it is centered so you can use that as a mark to check.

Here's an example with more content inside the left and the right `span` tag, the middle still stays centered:

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
span.right {
width: 40%;
float: right;
text-align: left;
}
span.middle {
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
}
span.left {
width: 40%;
float: left;
text-align: right;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<nav>
  <span class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor ismet</span>
  <span class="middle">middle</span>
  <span class="right">right is a longer width perhaps, yes why not, more content is here.</span>
</nav>
```

Comment: +1 for this. Never in 15 years has this come up. It actually looks better with it just center to the page not to the middle area.

Comment: This probably isn't a preferred solution for the same reason above, it doesn't account for large text. It looks like it works because you use very little text. If you use a large amount of text then your solution doesn't work. The area is a solution that would be usable for the most amount of situations.

Comment: @user2671355 This solution does work even with large amount of texts, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/os8skzrd/1/

Comment: @Fahad Hasan Works here, but when I test before it did not. I check multiple times. It also shows you editted. So if you updated then great.

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardless of size of text, including run on text like "adsfasdfakajdsckfjdbsuacbkfacf"

```
<ul class="center-me">
  <li>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdf 1</li>
  <li>wertwertwertwertwertwetrwetr 2</li>
  <li>zxcvzxcvzxcvzcxvzxcvzxcvzxcv 3</li>
</ul>

.center-me {
   list-style:none;
   text-align:center;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:100%;
}

.center-me li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You can tweak the properties as needed.

EDIT:
Working version http://jsfiddle.net/ryuushinigami/r4Ldo3gh/